# Different method to write complex number in euler form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> How to write $z$ in euler exponential form?
>    $$z = 1 + \sin \theta + i\cos \theta$$

My try: use trignometry to get following, where $c$ and $s$ represent $\cos$ and $\sin$ of the angle $\theta / 2$ 
$$z = (c+s)^2 + i (c-s)(c+s) \\
  z=(c+s) (c+s +i(c-s)) \\
 z= \sqrt2(c+s) \left[\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+i\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]$$

So $$z = \sqrt 2 (c+s) \exp\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

**My question is that is there other way to simplify this without using trigonometries?**

Comment: I tried using geometry but even there you run into using trigonometry at some point, if you using formulas then they use trigonometry in their derivation.

Comment: ok thanks @Piyush !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$1+e^{2iu}=e^{iu}(e^{iu}+e^{-iu})=2\cos(u)e^{iu}$$

$$\sin\theta+i\cos\theta=e^{i(\frac{\pi}2-\theta)}$$

So applying this with $u=\frac{\pi}4-\frac{\theta}2$

We get $z=1+\sin\theta+i\cos\theta=2\cos(\frac{\pi}4-\frac{\theta}2)e^{i(\frac{\pi}4-\frac{\theta}2)}$